# JOIN not supported in LINQ to Access

Tags: c#, linq, ms-access

I am using a third-party package named "LINQ to Access" and I'm getting the following error:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException about "Does not support JOIN operator."

How can I solve it?

```
 using(var context = AccessTools.CreateDataConnection(connStr)) {
     var tMachine = context.GetTable < Machine > ();
     var tUserinfo = context.GetTable < USERINFO > ();
     var tCheckintoutFiltered = context.GetTable < CHECKINOUT > ().Where(o => o.CHECKTIME >= startTime && o.CHECKTIME <= endTime);

     var join1 = tCheckintoutFiltered.Join(
       tMachine,
       outer => outer.sn,
       inner => inner.sn, (outer, inner) => new {
         outer.USERID, outer.CHECKTIME, outer.CHECKTYPE, inner.MachineNumber
       });

     var join2 = join1.Join(
       tUserinfo,
       outer => outer.USERID,
       inner => inner.USERID, (outer, inner) => new AttendanceLogObject {
         Checktime = outer.CHECKTIME, Checktype = outer.CHECKTYPE, MachineNumebr = outer.MachineNumber, Badgenumber = inner.Badgenumber
       });


     foreach(var alo in join2) {
       list.Add(new AttendanceLogObject { Checktime = alo.Checktime., Checktype = alo.Checktype, MachineNumebr = alo.MachineNumebr, Badgenumber = alo.Badgenumber });
     }
```

}

Comment: Why not contact the author(s) of that package?

Answer (score 0):

If a package does not support a particular feature then the only ways to "solve" it are to:

1. persuade the developers of the package to implement the feature, or
2. if it is an open-source project, then download the source code for the package and implement the feature yourself.

Otherwise you will need to "work around" the problem using the features that the product *does* support. For example for tables [Participants] ...

```
ID  FirstName  MedalID  Event
--  ---------  -------  -----------
 1  Gord             1  Napping
 2  Helen            3  Daydreaming
```

... and [Medals] ...

```
ID  Name
--  ------
 1  Gold
 2  Silver
 3  Bronze
```

... I would really like to be able to do this:

```cs
var particips = from p in db.Participants 
                join m in db.Medals on p.MedalID equals m.ID 
                select new { p.FirstName, MedalName = m.Name, p.Event };
foreach (var particip in particips)
{
    Console.WriteLine(
            "{0} won a {1} medal in \"{2}\"", 
            particip.FirstName, 
            particip.MedalName, 
            particip.Event);
}
```

but if `join` is not supported I might have to do something like this instead:

```cs
var medalNames = new Dictionary<int, string>();
var medals = from m in db.Medals select m;
foreach (var medal in medals)
{
    medalNames.Add(medal.ID, medal.Name);
}
var particips = from p in db.Participants 
                where p.MedalID != null
                select p;
foreach (var particip in particips)
{
    Console.WriteLine(
            "{0} won a {1} medal in \"{2}\"", 
            particip.FirstName, 
            medalNames[(int)particip.MedalID],
            particip.Event);
}
```